# Stopping all SSH Connections at once

Tags: c#, linux, multithreading, ssh, backgroundworker

I'm working on a program that's supposed to establish "n" many SSH connections with a remote Linux server, and run time consuming commands on each connection. The "time consuming operation" is basically running a script that sets up Wireshark and listens to the traffic.

For this I'm using the SharpSSH library for C# and n many BackgroundWorkers as threads. Also for simplicity, the code below has n=2 BGW threads and SSH connections.

Code:

```
    // runs when start is pressed
    private void startButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
        clickTime = timeNow.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"); // store the exact time of the click
        bw = bwArray[0];
        int index = 0; // ignore these 2 constants

        foreach (BackgroundWorker bgw in bwArray)
        {
            if (bgw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bgw.RunWorkerAsync(); 
                // runWorkerAsync for every BackgroundWorker in the array
                //index++;
            }
        }

    }
```

---

```
    // runWorkerAsync leads the BGWorker to this function
    private void bw_doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // let the UI know of button changes
            int p = 0;
            object param = "something"; // use this to pass any additional parameter back to the UI
            worker.ReportProgress(p, param);
            // UI notifying part ends here

            // for the simplex case
            if (numberOfConnections == 1)
                startOperation();
            // for the multiplex case
            else if (numberOfConnections > 1)
            {
                //while (p < numberOfConnections)
                //{
                    multiStartOperation();
                //  p++;
                //}
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

    }
```

---

```
    // will be called for all ssh connections (in multiplex case)
    private void multiStartOperation()
    {
        string[] command1Array = { "host2", "host2" };
        string[] command2Array = { clickTime + "_h2", clickTime + "_h2" };

        for (int index = 0; index < numberOfConnections; index++)
        {
            // shellArray is an array of SshExec objects
            shellArray[index] = new SshExec(IPAddress, username, password);
            try
            {
                shellArray[index].Connect();
            }
            catch (JSchException se)
            {
                Console.Write(se.StackTrace);
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Couldn't connect to the specified port.", "Connection Error!");
            }

            sb.Append(shellArray[index].RunCommand(command1Array[index]) + Environment.NewLine);
            // first command is host3, or host4 etc.

            // below is the time consuming command to run 
            string command = "./logcap.sh -c " + command2Array[index] + " -z";
            // sb is a global stringBuilder object,
            // to which the command output is appended
            sb.Append(shellArray[index].RunCommand(command));
        }

    }
```

My problem is the following:

When I press the start button on the GUI, both connections should start and run the script. Whereas in the code given above, the first index of shellArray (which consists of SshExec objects) gets connected, prepares the commands and runs the time consuming command, at which point the program goes back to the UI, without even starting the second connection. This is obviously because of the for loop, but I couldn't figure out how to work around this yet.

I need to get the other backgroundworker to establish and run the second command with the second server, so that when I press the stop button on the GUI all connections and threads can stop all together.

PS: The commands will not stop running unless the user clicks stop, which sends a Ctrl-C signal to the server.

I'm relatively new to all the multithreading and networking concepts, so if there is any confusion or mistake please let me know.

Have a nice day.

Comment: 1) I'd suppose you at least tell us if the `RunWorkerAsync` gets called (`bgw.IsBusy` is false) in the second round.

Comment: 2) How do you initialize the `bwArray`?

Comment: 3) Would you update your question title to describe the actual problem (=you are not able to run multiple background workers/connections)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, and the welcome. :)
The problem indeed was not being able to run multiple backgroundworkers at the same time.

I managed to solve the issue. It turns out that all I had to figure out was how to assign backgroundworkers to SSH connections. To do that, I created a class as follows:

```
    class BGW
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bgw;
        private int index;
        //getters, setters, constructors...
    }
```

After this, I converted bwArray which was an array of BackgroundWorkers into an array of BGW objects. At initialization, I assigned each BGW object an index.

Instead of having the stupid loop within multiStartOperation(), I sent an integer parameter to multiStartOperation() and that function used that index to reach the allocated backgroundworker.

So far it seems to work. 
Have a nice day.